# Displaying X and y axis in pylab

Tags: python, matplotlib

Is there a way in pylab to display the X and Y axis?  I know using grid() will display them, but it comes with numerous other lines all given the same emphasis.

Comment: What do you mean?  Can you give a code example?

Comment: @Nope - "Is there a way in pylab to display the X and Y axis?" what don't you understand about the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like your problem has been addressed in the new [Matplotlib 0.99](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/users/whats_new.html) with the Axis spine placement feature. Take a [look at the examples](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/examples/pylab_examples/spine_placement_demo.html#pylab-examples-spine-placement-demo).

Answer (score 8):

If you are looking to name the axis you can using the label function:

```
import pylab
pylab.xlabel("X")
pylab.ylabel("Y")
pylab.plot(range(10))
pylab.show()
```

Anyway, I'm pretty sure the x and y axis are automatically generated.

[matplotlib axes documentation](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.axes)

If you just want an empty plot then:

```
pylab.plot([None], [None])
```

this will give you the x and y axis with both going from 0 to 1.  Now if you would like to change the range of either of those then you can:

```
pylab.xlim(xmin=0, xmax=100)
pylab.ylim(ymin=0, ymax=100)
```

hope that helps.

Comment: This provides a label on the bottom and left side, but I was trying to make the x and y axis with the origins stand out.  One way I found to approximate this is to plot the functions x = 0 and y = 0, which gets close to what I want.  Is there a more graceful way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

What plot function do you use?

Axis are drawn automatically by all plotting functions I've seen so far, e.g.

```
from pylab import *
hist(randn(10000), 100)
show()
```

Additionally, axis can be generated manually with the [axes() function](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.axes).

Answer (score 1):

`foo.grid(b=True)` should help, but it is very raw.

If you supply any of the additional arguments it automatically assumes that b is True

For example:

```
foo.grid(label='My awesome grid')
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  Turning on the grid provides the entire grid, is there some way to only display the x and y axis?  Or at least to emphasize those two?

Comment: No idea how to emphasize them. But you can deemphasize the plots themselves and the axes will look greater.

Comment: That would work to make the grid stand out, but I am looking for a way to have a grid just for the 0 values.  I can get close to this by plotting x = 0 and y = 0 over the same range of values as my main function, but this seems inelegant at best.

Answer (score 1):

The best way for me is to add vertical and horizontal lines at 0:

```
pylab.axvline(linewidth=0.5, color = 'k')
pylab.axhline(linewidth=0.5, color = 'k')
```

Comment: This doesn't really add anything, the accepted answer already gives a good solution.